# Slick slideshow dots showing up as weird characters

Tags: css, slick.js

I'm using slick.js to create a slideshow. All is working well except the dots. They're showing up, but they're showing up as this weird character string (http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/40for10/img/slideshow/weird_chars.png).

My code seems right. What's wrong?

jquery:

```
$('#slideshow2').slick({
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-left'></i>",
    nextArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-right'></i>",
    accessibility: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            dots: true
});
```

css:

```
.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **[download](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#go-get-it)** and import Slick's CSS files as following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

It is an ***encoding issue*** as Mindaugas suggested.

Matheus's solution is misleading, you do ***not*** have to download the css file although this works because in the actual `.css` file the **encoding** is stipulated.

For instance, I did not download the css and was successful pulling from a CDN simply by adding a `charset="UTF-8"` attribute to my `<link>` tag.

Full solution would look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" charset="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 3):

meta charset="utf-8" << thats it

Answer (score 0):

In my case i needed to go into the `slick-theme.css` file and remove the IE fix (only using on safari and chrome) and then change the font it was using to use the `.ttf` not `.otf` file.

That sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE, JUST GO :

-in, **slick-theme.css**, go to **.slick-dots li button:before**, go to, **content: 'PUT YOUR VALUE'**

Just put a dot (or whatever you prefer).

(all others solutions I found in forums didn't work for me, then I found this EASY solution.